# Searching package repositories by contents

Tags: package-management, repository, latex

I am searching for a particular LaTeX input file, and have not been able to find it in the repositories.

I am fairly certain that the repositories can be searched by contents because the following command (searching for the LaTeX input file `amsmath.sty`) is successful:

```
# apt-cache search amsmath
texlive-latex-base - TeX Live: Basic LaTeX packages
texlive-doc-it - TeX Live: Italian documentation
texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: LaTeX supplementary packages
texlive-math-extra - TeX Live: Advanced math typesetting
```

The particular TeX input file I am searching for returns no results (`apt-cache search breqn`). Can I assume that `breqn.sty` is not present in any packages in the repositories, and thus seek it out through other means (e.g., CTAN)? Or might there be another way to search through package contents?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use apt-file to search for files within packages

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file

# Update database
sudo apt-file update

# Search for files
apt-file search foo

# or in your case
apt-file search breqn.sty
```

I get `texlive-latex3: /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/mh/breqn.sty` , so ...

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex3
```

See also http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-find-missing-packages-with-apt-file

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `apt-file update`. I had thought that `apt-get update` would have applied to `apt-file` as well, but this turned out not to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `texlive-latex3`. I found this out by installing [apt-file](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/apt-file) [image: Install apt-file] and using it like so:

```
apt-file update
apt-file search breqn.sty
texlive-latex3: /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/mh/breqn.sty
```

Which gives me the package name and the file.

- [How do I figure out what package something is in without resorting to Google?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34704/how-do-i-figure-out-what-package-something-is-in-without-resulting-to-google)

Comment: @user001 This is a site about Ubuntu not debian, you need to ask your question on unix.stackexchange.com if it's about Debian.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, it worked. I needed to run `apt-file update` as @bodhi-zazen pointed out. I thought `apt-get update` would be sufficient, but I guess they maintain separate package caches. I knew in this case the results would be equally useful to ubuntu and debian users, so that's why I posted it. I use both.

Comment: @user001 When I installed it on mine it prompted me to update it automatically, I've updated my answer to be sure though.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out I already had `apt-file` installed on my system without realizing it, so that's why I wasn't prompted. I probably hadn't run `apt-file update` in a while.