# How do I replace the following missing files?

Tags: software-center, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I figure out what package something is in without resorting to Google?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34704/how-do-i-figure-out-what-package-something-is-in-without-resorting-to-google)

I am getting the following errors with software center

```
 file does not exist: /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/apt/__init__.py
 file does not exist: /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py
 file does not exist: /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/view/__init__.py
 file does not exist: /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/view/widgets/__init__.py
```

Comment: @EliahKagan Ok, I get your point: not being able to use the software center does add an additional hurdle. I (morally) rescind my close vote.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

Comment: if issue fixed then let us know by accepting the answer by selecting the mark symbol .