# PCRE2-10.00 and xymon

Tags: compiling

When I `configure` and `make install` *PCRE2-10.00* and go to `xymon-4.3.18` to configure I get the following:

```
Checking for PCRE ...
test-pcre.c:1:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [test-compile] Error 1
ERROR: Cannot compile using PCRE library.
gcc: error: test-pcre.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [test-link] Error 1
ERROR: Cannot link with PCRE library.
Missing PCRE include- or library-files. These are REQUIRED for xymond
PCRE can be found at http://www.pcre.org/
If you have PCRE installed, use the "--pcreinclude DIR" and "--pcrelib DIR"
options to configure to specify where they are.
```

Don't know what to do. I was trying things but no success. Can some one help me or gives me advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the PCRE development files package:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
```

If the build configuration script still doesn't find it (which I find unlikely, because the header files are placed in a standard location), use:

```
./configure --pcreinclude /usr/include
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. :) now I have other problems with installation of xymon-4.3.18.

Comment: Thank you and sorry mait. Anyway it relay helped. I'm new to Linux. How did you know the name of the file (libpcre3-dev) or what to install if something is missing?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/34704/175814